# Tool to detect and visualize memory transfers and access

Tags: debugging, profiling, memory-profiling

I have a problem with a piece of C code computing a LU decomposition of a sparse matrix. There I write some different routine with various optimizations. Depending on the structure of the non zero elements in the matrix some implementation gets really fast but for the next example matrix it is getting too slow. Now I need a tool which profiles the application and shows me where where the code waits for new data from the memory and/or how the cache is used.  I already tried valgrind(cachegrind/callgrind) but the overhead is too large and the ration between the runtimes of the different implementations changed completely.

Are there any other OpenSource tools(Linux, BSD) to analyze memory traffic and similar problems? They should not use a Kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with Memory Profiler

Comment: Please more details, where I can get it and so on.